# Could you run a computer using a different base to base 1 (binary)

Tags: cv.computer-vision

I was wondering whether you could run a computer of a different system to binary using different degrees of certainty (more that just true and false - maybe true, false and possibly)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes its possable but alot of work to do. In the early days of computing base 10 was debated insted of binary but they decided to go with binary due to the fact that binary has only two valtage states and can have a higher fault torance and is just easyer to use and impament.
There is also qauntum computing which can run in three states which are spin up and spin down and a superposition. Qauntum computing relise on a few facts about qauntum mechanics such as when an electron isnt obsurbed then it can be in both states spin up and spin down  which is called a superpositon and when it is been obsurbed then it will choose it state either spin up or spin down. So qautium computing realys on alot of probabilty basicly. This is a simple explaintion because i dont have the time so please dont get mad. These links might help :

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing
- http://www.dwavesys.com/quantum-computing

  This one talks about base 3 and 4 use.
- quora/Why-do-computers-use-base-2-instead-of-base-10
- m.reddit/r/askscience/comments/254wpp/why_do_computers_still_use_binary_instead_of_a/